# What causes "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channels isn't new" in QuickBlox android?

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox

I'm using QuickBlox 2.3.3 SDK in my app and it keeps crashing ramdomly with this stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channels isn't new
at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession$4.run(QBRTCSession.java:565)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.LooperExecutor.run(LooperExecutor.java:63)
```

The stack trace does not point to any Class in my source code, so I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can somebody help me?

My app uses Videocalling and its crashing in aprox. 33% of calls made. The crash occurs before receiving/seeing video from my peer.

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you have forgot to initialize class `final QBUser user = new QBUser(login, password);` or any other class named `QBRTCSession`, without code i can guess this only, please update code

Answer (score 0):

Updating SDK version should solve the issue

[webrtc_android](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android)

Answer (score 0):

This exception sometimes means that you are either calling yourself or having duplicate opponent in your opponents list.
Make sure to clear your opponents list before adding the opponents you want to call.